# how to pivot only specific columns in a python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I am trying to create a process where I upload certain editable pdf data parse through the editable pdfs and then arrange the data in a df. I have managed to read the data in the editable pdfs and get them into a df, but I have run into an issue where the names on the individuals are appearing across the df as columns rather than individual row  for each player, currently the rows for each player are appearing  as name_#, position_#, country_# ...

This is not the actual data I am using just recreating the scenario I am facing.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Team': ["Bayern", "Barcelona", "Madrid"],
    'region': ["Bravaria", "Barcelona", "Madrid"],
    'title': ["Bundesliga", "Laliga", "Champions Leauge"],
    'name_1': ["Robben", "Messi", "Ronaldo"],
    'Position_1': ["RW", "ST", "ST"],
    'Country_1': ["Netherlands", "Argentina", "Portugal"],
    'name_2': ["Ribery", "Neymar", "Benzema"],
    'Position_2': ["LW", "LW", "RW"],
    'Country_2': ["FRANCE", "Brazil", "France"]})
```

|  | Team | region | title | name_1 | Position_1 | Country_1 | name_2 | Position_2 | Country_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Bayern | Bravaria | Bundesliga | Robben | RW | Netherlands | Ribery | LW | FRANCE |
| 1 | Barcelona | Barcelona | Laliga | Messi | ST | Argentina | Neymar | LW | Brazil |
| 2 | Madrid | Madrid | Champions Leauge | Ronaldo | ST | Portugal | Benzema | RW | France |

I am trying to find a way to  reposition pivot the DF so that it can look like the df shared below:
Each Team is a different pdf, but the structure is all the same.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Team': ["Bayern", "Barcelona", "Madrid", "Barcelona", "Madrid", "Bayern"],
    'region': ["Bravaria", "Barcelona", "Madrid", "Barcelona", "Madrid", "Bravaria"],
    'title': ["Bundesliga", "Laliga", "Champions Leauge", "Laliga", "Champions Leauge", "Bundesliga"],
    'name': ["Robben", "Messi", "Ronaldo", "Neymar", "Benzema", "Ribery"],
    'Position': ["RW", "ST", "ST", "ST", "RW", "LW"],
    'Country': ["Netherlands", "Argentina", "Portugal", "Brazil", "France", "France"]})
```

|  | Team | region | title | name | Position | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Bayern | Bravaria | Bundesliga | Robben | RW | Netherlands |
| 1 | Barcelona | Barcelona | Laliga | Messi | ST | Argentina |
| 2 | Madrid | Madrid | Champions Leauge | Ronaldo | ST | Portugal |
| 3 | Barcelona | Barcelona | Laliga | Neymar | ST | Brazil |
| 4 | Madrid | Madrid | Champions Leauge | Benzema | RW | France |
| 5 | Bayern | Bravaria | Bundesliga | Ribery | LW | France |

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what [`wide_to_long()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) is for.

```
pd.wide_to_long(
    df,
    ['name', 'Position', 'Country'],
    i='Team',
    j='n',
    sep='_',
)
```

```
                region             title     name Position      Country
Team      n
Bayern    1   Bravaria        Bundesliga   Robben       RW  Netherlands
Barcelona 1  Barcelona            Laliga    Messi       ST    Argentina
Madrid    1     Madrid  Champions Leauge  Ronaldo       ST     Portugal
Bayern    2   Bravaria        Bundesliga   Ribery       LW       FRANCE
Barcelona 2  Barcelona            Laliga   Neymar       LW       Brazil
Madrid    2     Madrid  Champions Leauge  Benzema       RW       France
```